# telegram-desktop does not start

Tags: permissions, apparmor

Suddenly, telegram-desktop has stopped working on my laptop. I am running the snap version 3.2.0 on ubuntu 20.04. From the command line, or using the GUI, it stops immediately. I have found 2 errors: one in /var/log/syslog:

```
 telegram-deskto[72764]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

and the final message in ~/snap/telegram-desktop/3323/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/log_start%.txt reads:

```
Failed to start listening to /run/user/221/snap.telegram-desktop/2261ece9ff43f98cfd03b389ad3b6xxx-{87A94AB0-E370-4cde-98D3-ACC110C59yyy} server: QLocalServer::listen: Name error
```

I have searched both errors on forums, but could not find any solution. I have re-installed the snap package, deleted the local data (~/snap/telegram-desktop/), updated all deb packages, restarted the machine, without luck. I did not spot any sign of self-upgrade of telegram, but I am not totally sure. I have created a new account on the same machine and telegram-desktop runs perfectly under this new account. The first error shows up as well under this new account, so I am assuming it is harmless, although these messages appeared in syslog at the time it stopped working under my primary account. I have run it under strace, and found that the canberra library it misses (which causes the first error) exists below /usr/lib, but the executable tries to open it without success (ENOENT), which is puzzling. I was not able to track anything corresponding to the second error, and I have no idea what it really means. I am suspecting some apparmor issue, but could not find anything clear in syslog.

I am really stuck, and would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then it may a good aportunity to try well packaged deb-version. At first remove snap by

```
sudo snap remove telegram-desktop
```

and then add [corresponding PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eatareao/+archive/ubuntu/telegram) and install Telegram from it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y telegram
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! ! didn't know that there was a ppa that delivers the stable version in deb format, which I tend to prefer over snap. This experience strengthens my inclination.

Comment: In my case: sudo apt upgrade