# How to update telegram desktop in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, telegram

Today **December 2nd** I received this message from **Telegram service notifications** about my outdated Desktop app version:

> Please update your app to the latest version. The version you are using is out of date and will stop working soon.

...In **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS** the latest released version of Telegram Desktop app is **2.1.7**, I ask to you for upgrade soon the repo for LTS with the last version of Telegram, please!

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1379276/124466) is a related question for ARM.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling your version and simply downloading the latest version [from the Telegram website](https://desktop.telegram.org/) (click `Show all platforms`). They offer [a Snap](https://snapcraft.io/telegram-desktop), [a Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.telegram.desktop), and a simple [`tar.xz`](https://telegram.org/dl/desktop/linux). For extracting the `tar.xz`, see [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/a/107976). That is probobly the easiest way. Alternately, you could file a bug report against the package, and the maintainer might update it

Comment: AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, "staffed" by volunteers. We don't have anything to do with what software is in repositories. Canonical, a for-profit company, handles that. Read `man ubuntu-bug` and report your problem/ request to Canonical.

Comment: @user535733 `telegram-desktop | 2.1.7+ds-2~ubuntu20.04.1 | focal-updates/universe  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64` I suspect, https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=telegram-desktop so possibly https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/telegram-desktop   (I had a *like* issue awhile back & switched from *deb* to *snap* but didn't explore...)

Comment: Maybe Ubuntu should either update Telegram like Firefox or Thunderbird, or drop the package.

Comment: @cocomac Please rewrite your comment into an answer.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Sorry. I've made a proper answer

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the correction!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [telegram-desktop does not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373839/telegram-desktop-does-not-start) . I'm using telegram from here, it got updates regularly, it does not complain about "stop working".

Comment: Just for completeness; someone recently filed a bug report on this issue - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/telegram-desktop/+bug/1953580

Answer (score 7):

If the source you have isn't updated, you could file an issue and perhaps the maintainer will update it. Of course, make sure your system is up to date first (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`).

Before trying any of these, remove whatever you already have. If you [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1378912/edit) to include how you installed it, we can try to help you undo that.

There are a multitude of ways to get the updated version. I've ordered these best-to-worse (in my opinion)

1. The [official download link](https://telegram.org/dl/desktop/linux) - Warning: direct download. It produces a `tar.xz`. See [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92328/how-do-i-uncompress-a-tarball-that-uses-xz/107976#107976) for the ways to extract it. Tl;dr: `tar xf archive.tar.xz` (credit to [@ramslök](https://askubuntu.com/users/45740/ramsl%c3%b6k) for that)
2. The [snap package](https://snapcraft.io/telegram-desktop) - Snap is a quick and easy way to install packages, and installing Telegram via Snap is very simple
3. [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.telegram.desktop) - Flatpak is good as well, but I find that Snap is better supported by default in Ubuntu, so I'd suggest Snap over Flatpak
4. Un-official PPA's - There are some unofficial PPA's like [this one](https://launchpad.net/%7Eatareao/+archive/ubuntu/telegram), but unless you have a really good reason to not use the three official methods, I don't suggest this. Regardless, here is how you would add that one

   ```
   $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install telegram
   ```

Comment: For a few more ways you can install it, see [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425716/how-to-install-telegram)

Comment: I have not used regular Ubuntu (GNOME DE) for a while, but is not right click -> extract here a much simpler choice to extract the .tar.xz?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Not for those that like to use the terminal for everything   :)

Comment: These snaps are really weird, I already had the snap one, it was stuck at 3.1.1 and the GUI Snap Store was showing "no updates". But when I did `sudo snap install telegram-desktop` it updated to 4.10.3, or so the command-line said. When I started telegram-desktop its Settings menu was still showing 3.1.1 and some newer messages in some channels were still showing as unsupported because of my Telegram version. These most-recommended options sure look like the most inconvenient to install and keep updated vs. PPAs. (SMH)

Answer (score 2):

update your telegram desktop to visit the store https://snapcraft.io/store  or update via command line

`sudo snap install telegram-desktop`

`sudo apt update`

Answer (score 2):

Telegram has self-updater, even if you use portable

[image: telegram update]