# Telegram claims I haven't installed latest version

Tags: xubuntu, versions, telegram

Dell Latitude e6530 Xubuntu 20.04 (.3?)
Keep getting Telegram message on login attempts that I have an outdated version. Tried installing Snap & Flappak from Telegram's link, but neither worked.
Found no help from:
[How to update telegram desktop in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378912/how-to-update-telegram-desktop-in-ubuntu-20-04)
either

Also installed Telegram purple, same result

Other suggestions?

Comment: What version of telegram do you currently vave, and how did you originally insta

Comment: When I typed "telegram --version" I got told I had the parameters wrong. When I typed "telegram-desktop --version" it started Telegram, but wouldn't let me login.
(What is it about me and logins?)

Answer (score 0):

Snap has an `edge` track with a newer version than you get with the normal version.

Snap install will normally install version *3.4.3*, but retrieving from the edge track, as in:

```
snap install --edge telegram-desktop
```

will yield version *3.4.8-45-g1e1f7be70 2022-01-28* .

You should probably get rid of the old first.

EDIT:

If you use the command `which telegram-desktop`, it will tell you what one is first in line to be run.

The way it decides is by looking at the $PATH variable **in ltr order**. So if the paths in the list are `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:~/.local/bin`, then a call to `command` will first look for `/usr/bin/program`. If it finds it, it will use that one. If not, it will try the next. If it makes it through the list without finding anything, it will give the error `no such command` or something like that. This is how you can manipulate which version runs. Make sure it is the first one it sees.

Alternatively, you can run any version that you have installed by providing the full path on the command line.

One last tip: For snaps, you can use the command `snap info name` to find out version info. Telegram-desktop doesnt have much of a command line interface, I guess because they also offer `telegram-cli` as an option. They must expect users of the command line to grab that one.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Thought I found how to remove Telegram files & directories, but it didn't work: When I tried to install with edge, it returned "already installed". Does the path start with /home/hulda or with .local/share or with TelegramDesktop. I think I tried all 3 variations. No success. I'd like to know enough basics to be able to follow contributors' suggestions, if with a little lookup help. But it seems I'm still too raw of a beginner. Any suggestions of how to get up to speed? I really don't want to get back into Geekland. I just want a reliable non-Evil Empire computer.

Comment: Now I see that I have 2 Telegrams listed in the (catface/whiskers) menu  - one that works (!) and one that doesn't. Tried removing the duplicate using the Internet menu, as I saw suggested, but didn't work. At least I've been able to label the dud. 
I'm slowly making progress, but spending way too many hours - for over a week - just trying to get my Xubuntu Dell laptop setup so I can use it productively. {sigh}

Comment: I know the feeling, but the system that youll end up with will be one that you know on an intimate level, as it will be one that you built. And everything that you pick up along the way will make it worthwhile, I promise. : )

Comment: The app installed with snap should start with `/snap/telegram-desktop`. Snap and apt (dpkg) both have subcommands for removing packages that they track (usually that means those installed by them). For apt installs, it is `apt-remove`. add `--purge` to the cmd to remove the configuration data as well. For snap, I beleive it is `snap remove`, but I am not sure without looking it up. To master the usage of these commands, run the command  `man -a {dpkg,apt,snap}`. Each time you finish reading a page, hit <kbd>q</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: It is a lot of reading, but will save you a lot of time in the long run. also try `command --help` for a quick rundown of allowed usages. Oh yea almost forgot. Its too late. Youre already in Geekland.

Comment: Sucked back into Geekland: Was afraid of that. OK, so this time when I ran **bold** sudo updatedb && locate Telegram **bold** I found a snap install as well. I'm guessing that's the one that's working. But how to be sure before I go deleting anything? What does **bold** <kbd>q</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> **bold** do? Or will man tell me? BTW I just discovered that this eBay laptop came w/4Gb instead of 16Gb RAM as advertised, so I may need to return it. Oh joy. 
BTW again: "yea" is pronounced "yay" (which is why I always spell it yay to avoid confusion). You may have meant "yeah".

Comment: Snap run procedure  is a bit tricky to understand. It makes links to programs at runtime. Google 'how does snap work ubuntu'.

Comment: So far Telegram (one of my "installs") is working fine, so I better not fix what ain't broke. Thanks for the tip, though. Guess this is the end of this thread, as I've been given notice twice to avoid extended discussions in Comments, although I don't have enough "points" to move a discussion to chat. Perhaps you'll respond to one of my next questions and move to chat if need be since I can't: Whether it's advisable to have 16 Gb vs 4 Gb on a Dell Latitude e6530 for Xubuntu 20.04. And: How to effect a stable installation of Zoom. I've seen some tales of woe here.